# How to solve the following ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $\int _{0} ^{t} f(v)f(t-v) dv=\frac{1}{2}(sin(t)-tcos(t))$

I've tryed use laplace transform like this:
$$F^2(s)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{1}{1+s^2}-\frac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}\big)$$

But, i don't believe that exist (in the easy way) the laplace transform of a root.

Im doing this well?.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{1}{1+s^2}-\frac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}\big) = \frac {1}{(s^2+1)^2}$.  So finding that root won't be so hard.

Comment: try making a common denominator and adding the fractions